# Trying out the examples from the "The Little Schemer" book in Windows

Tags: lisp, scheme

I am currently reading 'The Little Schemer' and I need a way to test out the Scheme examples in the book on my Windows machine.

With what application can I do this (on Windows, not Linux)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/) is a very good self-contained Scheme development environment available for several platforms including Windows. It comes with several flavors of Scheme, an IDE with a debugger, and a ton of Scheme libraries for real-world programming.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of scheme implementations. PLT Scheme is good on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) might work for you.

MIT/GNU Scheme is an implementation of the Scheme programming language, providing an interpreter, compiler, source-code debugger, integrated Emacs-like editor, and a large runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to install anything on your system. Just click the following site and you are ready to test the examples given in the book.

http://repl.it/languages/Scheme